# viewpathing in postgres (private/individual versions of otherwise globally available tables)

Tags: postgresql, search-path, libpqxx

I want to create a test environment where the basic underlying postgres database is overlain with an instance-localized private view, such that all queries from a specific set of processes go through the private view while other (potentially concurrent or merely subsequent) processes would remain unaffected.

I think I can do something like this using the *search_path* mechanism, but it's not clear if I can do that transparently (e.g., without having each application execute some set of SQL setup for each connection).  For example, is there something I could set as an environment variable saying "use this search_path" and have every process that I start thereafter see that and use the same private table instances?

If it matters, the processes are all going through the C++ adapter, libpqxx, to access the database.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every instance has a separate database user role, you can simply create a schema with the same name as the user and it'll use it -- without any change to configuration:

```
myuser=> show search_path;
 search_path   
--------------
"$user",public
(1 row)

myuser=> create schema myuser;
CREATE SCHEMA
myuser=> create table foo(i int);
CREATE TABLE
myuser=> \d foo
   Table "myuser.foo"
Column  Type   Modifiers 
------ ------- ---------
i      integer
```

If you want to have different names for users and schemas, you can configure it for each user manually:

```
ALTER USER foo SET search_path=foo_schema;
```

Comment: In my case, I'm using the same underlying user to access the database. I think for that I can probably modify the search_path on a per-process basis by doing something like set PGOPTIONS='-c search_path=test,public', right?

Comment: Indeed, any libpq-based PostgreSQL adapter supports PGOPTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the default search path for all connections in the postgre configuration file.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-OTHER

If each connection needs some custom search path based on who the user is you will have to do that in your code and issue a `SET search_path TO x,y,z;`for each connection.

Another option that comes to mind is using stored functions and have them use dynamic sql to query from different schemas based on who the caller is. You would have to maintain a table or the more evil of the two "hard code" the user/schema mappings into the stored functions that the stored function would use.

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointer.  In my case, I want to potentially have other concurrent clients that aren't looking through the same search_path.  I think for that I can probably do something like set PGOPTIONS='-c search_path=test,public', right?